# Change paradigm to use WorkFlow

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation

Was wondering advantages/disadvantages of using WorkFlow in new development?  Seems like a bit of change of paradigm, wondering if it is worth the effort to incorporate.

Answer (score 1):

Before diving in to WF make sure to analyze the workflows that you want to implement. If they are fairly simple and/or short-lived I would think twice.

My experience is that it does pay off when the workflows may live for a long time (hours/days/weeks), especially in combination with a persistence service. In the project where I have used it we realized that of the two main workflows that we have, one of them would probably work just as fine without using WF.

The other one (which is packaging information in a mail that is sent over SMPT, and then expects one of a few predefined responses in a mailbox, and resending the message at certain intervals if no response arrives) I find to be a good case for WF.

Answer (score 1):

Dont bother with Workflow on desktop apps. Due to the multithreaded design (which is perfect for servers, particularly web servers), latency is quite high between state transitions.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't seem like a natural fit into your project you probably don't need it.